# Can't load local library in Python on Mac

Tags: python, installation, module, package, local

I am trying to import a local python library in Jupyter notebook, but I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

I also tried doing a pip install onto the path, but it states that it can't find `setup.py` when it is actually there.

I also changed my PythonPath in both my .bash_profile and .bashrc to point to where the package is, but still can't import the local package in my Jupyter notebook.

Below shows the steps to reproduce and the errors that I got (the local library is `analytics_utils`):

0. First I checked my sys.path to see if it contains the local package, which it does:

`'/Users/kevin.sun/Documents/Realself_dev/analytics-utils/analytics_utils'`

1. Running this code:  `from analytics_utils import bigquery as bqu`

yields the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4cad1fe376be> in <module>
----> 1 from analytics_utils import bigquery as bqu

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'analytics_utils'
```

2. I tried to do a pip3 install with the following code:

   `!pip3 install "/Users/kevin.sun/Documents/Realself_dev/analytics-utils/analytics_utils"`

But then I get the following error (the path does have a `setup.py` though):

```
ERROR: Directory '/Users/kevin.sun/Documents/Realself_dev/analytics-utils/analytics_utils' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

3. I added the following line to my .bash_profile but still can't load the library

`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/Users/kevin.sun/Documents/Realself_dev/analytics-utils/analytics_utils"`

4. I also added the following line to my .bashrc

`export PYTHONPATH = '/Users/kevin.sun/Documents/Realself_dev/analytics-utils/analytics_utils'`

None of these solutions have worked so far. Is there anything else I can try/ am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: try moving the project folder into the working the directory or go up one level on the path you've added to your path

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I tried adding the directory that was one level up into my sys.path, and it works now!